# Codeingiter 4 : "there is no data to update" exception

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm trying to understand up Codeingiter works with entity.

Here's my code from InterventionController.php :

```
$intervention = $this->interventionsModel->find($id);
$intervention->title    = $this->request->getVar("title");
$this->interventionsModel->save($intervention);
```

-> if i change the title into the form and if i click the "update" button : it works well (database get updates)

-> When i don't change the title and i just click the "update" button : it throws an exception :  "There is no data to update."

How can i use codeingiter 4 without getting that exception if no data have been changed by the user ?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue.  Is the value you're saving for title, the same as the value that is already set for the "intervention" object?

Comment: for a quick fix use a try catch block to handle `\CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DataException` exception

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue now. And in my case, the problem was that I didn't included the field that I was updating, in the `$allowedFields` array of my Model.

Have a look at this: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html#configuring-your-model

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    protected $allowedFields = ['name', 'email', 'is_email_verified'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save is a wrapper for update/insert.  When you know you're updating a record, you can use the update function, pass the variables in and the update will save, regardless of whether the properties of the record have changed.

```
$intervention = $this->interventionsModel->find($id);
$intervention->title    = $this->request->getVar("title");
$this->interventionsModel->update($id, [
 "title" => $intervention->title
]);
```

I think there should be a property of the model that turns this functionality off for the save() wrapper, but it doesn't appear there is.

Documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html?highlight=data%20update#saving-data

Comment: Hello Pendo, thanks for you answer. Indeed, this solution works but we lose the benefit of using save for both insert / update in a save function.
It, indeed, appears that there is not solution offered by CI :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $this->obj->update($id, $p);
```

Instead of:

```
   $this->obj->where('id',$id)->update( $p);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value from form is empty or not and use the IF Condtion

```
$intervention = $this->interventionsModel->find($id);
if($this->request->getVar("title"))
{
   $intervention->title    = $this->request->getVar("title");
   $this->interventionsModel->save($intervention);
} else {
  // title is empty or null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your protected $allowedFields = ['firstName','lastName','email','mobileNumber','Password','isActive']; like mine i allowed ci to change these fields data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).